# RxJS5 Operator that can handle wrapped *and* unwrapped values?

Tags: rxjs5, angular2-observables

With Promises, if you do this:

```
    Promise.resolve(p).then(function(){
      return 5;
    })
   .then(function(val){
      return db.find(); // promise
    });
```

we can see that then operator on promises can handle any returned value, it just calls Promise.resolve() on the return result and handles it whether it's a promise or not.

However, with RxJS5, I am finding it difficult to find an operator that can do something similar. I get a lot of errors:

```
TypeError: You provided x where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at Object.subscribeToResult (/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/observable-persistent-queue/node_modules/rxjs/util/subscribeToResult.js:73:27)
    at MergeAllSubscriber._next (/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/observable-persistent-queue/node_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeAll.js:85:42
```

for example, with this:

```
Rx.Observable.range(1,9)
    .flatMap(function(){
        return Rx.Observable.timer(4)
    })
    .concatAll() // this will throw the error
    .subscribe();
```

is there an RxJS operator or pattern of operators that can handle any value and unwrap it like with Promises?

Answer (score 0):

There is as far as my knowledge goes no operator which takes anything and just works. MergeMap/switchMap/concatMap will work with array/promises/observables as return values and convert them to Observable streams. But not with regular values.

Comment: yeah I actually don't think it's that big of a deal, just would be semi-convenient for a certain call to be able to handle an Observable or plain value; if you really wanted you could create an operator that did handle both I guess